# Rigid type variable -- why no error appears?

Tags: haskell, type-systems, scoped-type-variables

In the following example I'm internally implementing the function `f`. Its signature is using `a` as if the type variable `a` is scoped, and it is working without giving me a compile error even though I haven't enabled the extension **`ScopedTypeVariables`**:

```
foo :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
foo n list = snd $ foldl f (1,[]) list where
  f :: (Int,[a]) -> a -> (Int,[a])
  f (k,l) r
    | k==n = (1,l++[r])
    | otherwise = (k+1,l)
```

I was expecting the error: `"Couldn't match type ‘a1’ with ‘a’ ...."` because, as I said, I was treating the type variable `a` as if it's scoped even though it is not scoped.

I know what a rigid type is, and I already know why the error appears. My question is why I'm *not* getting the error here.

Answer (score 4):

The function

```
f :: (Int,[a]) -> a -> (Int,[a])
f (k,l) r
  | k==n = (1,l++[r])
  | otherwise = (k+1,l)
```

is general enough to type check on its own (assuming `n::Int`). The type `a` here can indeed be any type -- there's no need to assume that `a` is the same `a` as the one in the signature of `foo`, so no error is generated.

Put in different terms, we could rename `a` into `b` without any harm:

```
foo :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
foo n list = snd $ foldl f (1,[]) list where
  f :: (Int,[b]) -> b -> (Int,[b])
  f (k,l) r
    | k==n = (1,l++[r])
    | otherwise = (k+1,l)
```

Here's a simpler example to stress the point. This compiles without errors:

```
foo :: a -> [a]
foo x = [f x]
   where
   f :: a -> a   -- this could also be b->b
   f y = y
```

By contrast, changing the last line to `f y = x` would immediately trigger the error since `x` has type "the `a` in the signature of `foo`", not "the `a` in the signature of `f`", and the two type variables can't be unified since they are both rigid.

Comment: If it's not much to ask could you alter f in a way in which the mentioned error is then generated? As in making f "not general" enough anymore.

Comment: @TarekSoliman One small change that would cause the error you want would be `| k==n = (1, take 1 (r:list))` -- note that I used `list` here and not `l`. Since `r` has the inner `a` in its type, and `list` has the outer `a` in its type, this is type correct only if the inner and outer `a`s are the same.

Comment: @TarekSoliman Your `f` only uses `n::Int` as a variable coming from the outermost function. Since the type of `n` does not involve `a`, it's general enough. By also using `list`, as Daniel showed, we can now mix the outer `a` and the inner `a`, triggering the error.

Answer (score 2):

```
foo :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
foo n list = snd $ foldl f (1,[]) list where
  f :: (Int,[a]) -> a -> (Int,[a])
  f (k,l) r
    | k==n = (1,l++[r])
    | otherwise = (k+1,l)
```

Notice how your inner function `f` only uses `n` from the outer function's scope. `n` is of type `Int`; only `list` (and `foo` itself) are names whose type has anything to do with the `a` variable in the type of `foo`. Since `f` doesn't use those, it doesn't *need* to have a type that uses `ScopedTypeVariables` to refer to the `a` from the type of `foo`.

In effet, `f` is fully polymorphic on its own; it can work with its own `a` instantiated to any type. Because it's only used in one place (inside `foo`) it will only ever actually be used with its `a` instantiated to the `a` from the outer `foo`. But that happens by exactly the same process any polymorphic type is instantiated in Haskell; the definition of `f` has to treat `a` as a black box and work with any possible type, and the place where `f` is **used** can instantiate it at anything (in this case, the `a` from the type of `foo`).

Lets show that more explicitly by using explicit foralls and not giving the same name to different type variables:

```
foo :: forall a. Int -> [a] -> [a]
foo n list = snd $ foldl f (1,[]) list where
  f :: forall b. (Int,[b]) -> b -> (Int,[b])
  f (k,l) r
    | k==n = (1,l++[r])
    | otherwise = (k+1,l)
```

`f` works `forall b`, and its only a coincidence of one particular usage that wants to instantiate `b ~ a` (even if that "one particular usage" is in fact the only usage).

The typical error in trying to write a type of a local function (that needs `ScopedTypeVariables` to resolve) is when the inner function uses something from the outer function that has a variable in its type. Say, something like this:

```
bar :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
bar f xs = filter g xs
  where g :: a -> Bool
        g = not . f
```

This might look fine at first glance, but the type signature for `g` is actually a lie, because without `ScopedTypeVariables` it means this:

```
bar :: forall a. (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
bar f xs = filter g xs
  where g :: forall b. b -> Bool
        g = not . f
```

It's claiming that `g` can take something of any type at all and turn it into a `Bool`, when in fact `g` uses the function `f`. `f` doesn't work on any type at all, only the particular type that `bar` was called with. `bar` can take a function `f` of any type (the caller of `bar` can choose to instantiate `a` as any type), but `g` is operating "inside one particular call to `bar`", when we've already been passed one particular `f`.

To write this type correctly we need (using `ScopedTypeVariables`) this:

```
bar :: forall a. (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
bar f xs = filter g xs
  where g :: a -> Bool
        g = not . f
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no error because your inner function does not reference any type variable from the outer one. It uses `n` but its type is plain `Int`, not a polymorphic one

The "rigid type variables" error happens when we make `n`'s type polymorphic:

```
foo :: Num a => a -> [a] -> [a]
foo n list = snd $ foldl f (1,[]) list where
  f :: Num a => (a,[a]) -> a -> (a,[a])
  f (k,l) r
    | k==n = (1,l++[r])
    | otherwise = (k+1,l)
```

Since all type signatures have an implicit `forall` added in front of them,  so does the one for `f`. And each `forall` defines its own scope.